# ClassNotFoundException android only on signed apk

Tags: android, eclipse, apk

I've a strange error with my android project. 
I've tested my code on device and everithing was ok, so i've signed my apk, and load it to play store. Now when i install my app from play store, my app crash whit

```
Failing to launch activity due to ClassNotFoundException
```

when app try to launch main activity.
So i've manually install apk's (signed and unsigned) on my device, and i've noticed that, unsigned apk works well, but signed apk give me the same error. 
How this could be possible, and how i can fix this error?

Comment: Do you have proguard enabled, it might cause issues

Comment: no, i don't have proguard enabled

Answer (score 0):

may be you have applied proguard seetings that removing file that is needed to run your app and its showing problem at run time in your you signed release apk, if so check your proguard settings
or check your database code if you have changes in dB and not changed you dB version ?

Comment: Proguard is not enabled, also because i don't know what is prouard until today!

Comment: plz post full logcat info of class not found exception

Comment: if you have heard first time about proguard, then may be you Dont know but proguard was working . to check it, if you using eclipse check your project properties file and proguard line should be commented by adding a # before it, if you using android studio then go to app module settings and set minimized flag in release flavour false. android project have a default proguard file that will be applied if this setting will be enabled, so please check it once